# Is the sexual act contrary to achieving enlightenment?

Tags: reference-request, sexual-misconduct

I remember reading in a sutta that the Buddha said not engaging in the sexual act is considered right action. Does anybody know the place where that is written? I don’t remember where I read it.

Comment: See [Is the Noble Eightfold Path a path of celibacy?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/36548/is-the-noble-eightfold-path-a-path-of-celibacy?r=SearchResults) and [Is celibacy intrinsic to Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2902/254)

Comment: I added the `reference-request` tag because I think that's what you were asking -- i.e. simply asking for a reference to the sutta where "not engaging in the sexual act" is "right action".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was referenced in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36550/254).

The word used there is *abrahmacariyā* and associated with celibacy.

That word used that way (celibacy) in the 3rd of the eight precepts -- see the references at the start of [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35116/254) -- a different word is used in the 3rd of the five precepts.

I think it has a broader meaning than celibacy though, e.g. it's used in [SN 54.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.2/en/sujato) -- so instead of or as well as "celibate" it's translated "the holy life" or "the spiritual life" -- I think it refers to a monk's life, including keeping the rules of the vinaya and the company of other monks.

Where it's used in SN 45.8, I note that the three types of wrong action which are listed there -- i.e. killing, stealing, and sexual intercourse -- correspond to [parajika](https://www.budsas.org/ebud/ebsut019.htm) offenses which result in someone's automatically losing their status as a monk or nun.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is satisfying.

Comment: this answer sounds wrong, which is why i original marked it down. there appears nothing in SN 45.2 that refers to a kalyāṇa­mittatā as exclusively a monk